# Rspec tests for multiple has_many, dependent destroy for a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have a model in rails which has mulitple has_many, :dependent => :destroy relationships in it.

```
class XYZ <ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :abc, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :def, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :ghi, :dependent => :destroy
.......
end
```

I have rpec tests in xyz controller:

```
describe 'destroy' do
it 'should destroy all the entities in has_many' do
 @xyz= FactoryGirl.create(:xyz)
 @abc= FactoryGirl.create(:abc, :xyz=> @xyz)
 @def= FactoryGirl.create(:def, :xyz=> @xyz)
 @ghi= FactoryGirl.create(:ghi, :xyz=> @xyz)
 expect { @xyz.destroy }.to change { ABC.count }.by(-1)
end 
end
```

How do I test whether destroying xyz actually decreases count of models Abc, Def and Ghi simultaneously? Or is the only way to do this is to write separate tests for individual has_many, dependent:destroy relationship?

Answer (score 0):

Use [rspec-collection_matchers](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-collection_matchers) and use this piece of code, don't test already tested stuff.

```
it { should have_many(:abc).dependent(:destroy) }
```